# pg_dump command not found in bash programming

Tags: bash, postgresql, macos, pg-dump

I create function in `~/.bash_profile` file to backup postgresql database like this:

```
function dbbackup(){
  pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U myuser -W mydatabase > /my/path
}
```

I get an output:

> dbbackup:1: command not found: pg_dump

If I run command directly in terminal:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U myuser -W mydatabase > /my/path
```

It works. How can I do that? I need to run `pg_dump` programmatically using bash programming.

Comment: Did you try providing the entire path to the pg_dump bin?

Comment: Yes, pg_dump is in path. I have tried this in path: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2/bin 
and 
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2/bin/pg_dump 
still doesn't work

Comment: Have you literally called pg_dump via its full path in the bash script? It doesn't matter if it's in your path or not.

Comment: A good place to start is to look at the output of `type pg_dump` in the environment where it works. If that returns you an absolute path *and that absolute path also fails in the script*, then we know there are other environment dependencies, f/e, on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (to control where shared libraries are loaded from).

Comment: Another place to start: Run `set -x` to enable trace logging; then invoke the function, and see if it prints any special characters in showing the command that it runs. Compare the trace log of the manual, working invocation with the programmatic, broken one.

Comment: ...all that said, there's absolutely nothing special about `pg_dump`. It's invoked the same way as any other external command (which is to say, through the `execv` family of syscalls), and nothing about invoking it from bash is different from invoking it from C, or Python, etc -- it's all through the same syscall interface, and subject to the same set of errors (errors originating from the OS itself, not from bash).

Comment: I try as @CharlesDuffy mentioned by replace pg_dump with absolute path `/usr/local/bin/pg_dump` it's work! Thanks.. So, problem is about path? In same case I call `psql` in another function, it's no need absolute path, but it's work.

Comment: If `/usr/local/bin/pg_dump` works but `pg_dump` does not (and `type` and `set -x` don't reveal something different going on like an alias or function overriding the name), then your `PATH` does not have `/usr/local/bin` in it (or else it has a different directory containing a broken version of `pg_dump` first, but that's much less likely).

Comment: Are you running the script as a cron job? cron jobs run with a very minimal environment (`PATH` etc), and don't run through a shell, so they don't use any shell init files (unless you somehow force them to).